# Ionic app does not work properly on android device

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 1. I have been making an app where I have used SQLite. The app runs perfectly on browser but works partially on device. There is a button that does not work. The code that contains this button is given below. The button function name is charge. Here's my code:

```
angular.module('app.cartCtrl', ['ngCordova'])

    .controller('cartCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$cordovaSQLite', '$ionicHistory', '$ionicPopup',// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

        $stateParams.parameterName
        function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup) {





            $scope.items = [];
            $scope.grandTotal = 0;
            $scope.receiptnumber = 0;
            $scope.receiptnumber = $scope.receiptnumber + 1;
            $scope.items = [];
            $scope.item = {};
            $scope.grandTotal = null;






            var query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE quantity!='' ";
            console.log(query2);
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query2, []).then(function (res) {

                if (res.rows.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                        $scope.items.push({

                            itemname: res.rows.item(i).itemname,
                            price: res.rows.item(i).price,
                            quantity: res.rows.item(i).quantity,


                        });


                        $scope.items = $scope.items;

                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("No results found");
                }
            }, function (err) {
                console.error("error=>" + err);
            });




            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();




            var query = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM items";


            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {


                $scope.grandTotal = res.rows[0]['SUM(total)'];

                //$scope.grandtotal = parseFloat(res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);
                // console.log("Grand total is" + res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);

            }, function (err) {
                console.error("error=>" + err);
            });












            $scope.myGoBack = function () {

                $state.go("menu.sales");


            };



            $scope.charge = function () {

                $state.go('transactionsuccess');


            }



        }])
```

I am in doubt with below piece of code. Will it work on device or emulator:

```
res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']
```

Comment: Why did I get a negative mark for this question? Please tell me so that I can correct myself next time.

Comment: what parameter ur passing in this select query  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query2, []).then(function (res) .since ur select  query doesn't contain any value it might show u the error if possible can u post your log details

Comment: The app runs perfect on browser. And the query I have used is what I want to achieve.

Comment: In browser u can't store the data's in SQLite only on real devices or emulator you have to check it out. But  the query you have given " select * from items WHERE quantity!=' ' "  $cordovaSQlite.execute u have passed [] empty array which won't give any result

Comment: oh ok. Then what could be a possible solution bro?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this updated query and check the post the log what ur getting

```
var query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE quantity!='' ";
console.log(query2);
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query2, [5]).then(function (res) {
if (res.rows.length > 0) {
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
$scope.items.push({
itemname: res.rows.item(i).itemname,
price: res.rows.item(i).price,
quantity: res.rows.item(i).quantity,
});
$scope.items = $scope.items;
}
} else {
console.log("No results found");
}
}, function (err) {
console.error("error=>" + err);
});
$ionicHistory.clearCache();
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
var query = "SELECT SUM(total) total FROM items";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {
console.log('Result: ', res);
$scope.grandTotal = res.rows[0].total;
//$scope.grandtotal = parseFloat(res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);
// console.log("Grand total is" + res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);
}, function (err) {
console.error("error=>" + err);
});
```

Comment: Did u just changed the query this query:   var query = "SELECT SUM(total) total FROM items";

Comment: @SoumyaRauth  yes i have changed it

Comment: I mean any other changes u made or only this one? I could not figure out.

Comment: @SoumyaRauth  what happened?

Comment: Why did u put [5] instead of []?

Comment: @SoumyaRauth  to check what log you are getting.If u pass [] means it won't give any result to you thats why i have added 5 in the parameter

Comment: The thing is my charge function does not consist of sqlite query. It only has a state.go... But, I don't know why this button isn't working on device. I am having problem debugging on device.. I tried ionic run android -l -c... but, didn't work

Comment: @SoumyaRauth try to add a console.log('Button clicked') before the state.go and check

Comment: @SoumyaRauth  share your log file